# Org mode not working as expected

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Running Doom Emacs 2.0.9 on Emacs 26.3.

I have a `test.org` as follows:

```
* h1                                                            :tag1:tag2:
* h2                                                                 :tag2:
** h21
** h22
* h3                                                                 :tag1:
** h31
** h32
```

`init.el` does not carry any customization for any org variable.

When I run `org-agenda m` it provides tag1 and tag2 to choose from. But when selected it does not produce any results. Can this be achieved without a predetermined list of agenda files?

When I do `org-sparse-tree m` for tag1, it continues to show the file as it is. I thought it would only show tag1 items.

What is wrong? How do I set things right?

Comment: With org-sparse-tree, does it not fold the h2 heading?

Comment: @NickD No. It doesn't. Hence, the question. I could understand no entries showing up in agenda view. But `org-sparse-tree` was totally unexpected

Comment: In my case, `org-sparse-tree m tag1` unfolds `h1` and `h3` and folds `h2`, If I select `tag2` then `h1` and `h2` are unfolded and `h3` is folded. I would suggest you run with `emacs -q` and a minimal init file, so that you can check whether your init file does something bad.

Answer (score 1):

If the value of `org-agenda-files` is a directory, by default all files with the extension `.org` will be considered for the agenda.  See `C-h v org-agenda-files` for more information.

Comment: Thanks. I can understand the agenda not showing. What is more surprising is that the sparse tree also is not showing. Or does `org-sparse-tree` also require the file to be an org-agenda file?